# How can I, in PHP, access the value of a serialized HTML form in a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, php, json

For this particular problem I need to send 2 serialized forms to my server at once plus a few values in JSON format. The structure of my JSON object will always look like the below:

```
"{  
  "startDate":"2015-07-20",
  "planName":"MySecondAttempt",
  "clientId":"5",
  "client_update_form":"client_id=5&squat_max=300&deadlift_max=100&bench_max=275",
  "user_id":3,
  "workoutDaysArray":[  
  "workoutDayName=Legs&copyUnderway=0&date=July+21&workoutId=4&setInstruction1=2&repInstruction1=4&weightInstruction1=6&restInstruction1=8&workoutId2=&setInstruction2=&repInstruction2=&weightInstruction2=&restInstruction2=",
  "workoutDayName=Arms&copyUnderway=0&date=July+23&workoutId=7&setInstruction1=1&repInstruction1=2&weightInstruction1=3&restInstruction1=4&workoutId2=2&setInstruction2=2&repInstruction2=4&weightInstruction2=6&restInstruction2=8&workoutId3=3&setInstruction3=2&repInstruction3=4&weightInstruction3=6&restInstruction3=8&workoutId4=&setInstruction4=&repInstruction4=&weightInstruction4=&restInstruction4="
 ]}"
```

I then access the object with the below:

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$trainerId          = $input['user_id'];
$workoutDaysArray   = $input['workoutDaysArray'];
$startDate          = $input['startDate'];
$planName           = $input['planName'];
$clientUpdateForm   = $input['client_update_form'];
```

So now the variable $workoutDaysArray, for instance hold the value of a serialized form represented as a string. I'm hoping there's a way to access the key value pairs in that serialized form without having to parse the string manually or rewrite a lot of javascript.

I was hoping something similar to this would work, but I think I may be off here:

```
foreach($workoutDaysArray as $key=>$value){
   //some code
}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!!

Comment: `json_decode()`? Show what you tried.

Comment: How about `json_decode()` ?

Comment: Like the other people said, use json_decode and if you want an associative array put true as second argument.

Comment: I'll update the answer now with some more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look with var_dump at your result:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (6) {
  ["startDate"]=>
  string(10) "2015-07-20"
  ["planName"]=>
  string(15) "MySecondAttempt"
  ["clientId"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["client_update_form"]=>
  string(56) "client_id=5&squat_max=300&deadlift_max=100&bench_max=275"
  ["user_id"]=>
  int(3)
  ["workoutDaysArray"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(219) "workoutDayName=Legs&copyUnderway=0&date=July+21&workoutId=4&setInstruction1=2&repInstruction1=4&weightInstruction1=6&restInstruction1=8&workoutId2=&setInstruction2=&repInstruction2=&weightInstruction2=&restInstruction2="
    [1]=>
    string(397) "workoutDayName=Arms&copyUnderway=0&date=July+23&workoutId=7&setInstruction1=1&repInstruction1=2&weightInstruction1=3&restInstruction1=4&workoutId2=2&setInstruction2=2&repInstruction2=4&weightInstruction2=6&restInstruction2=8&workoutId3=3&setInstruction3=2&repInstruction3=4&weightInstruction3=6&restInstruction3=8&workoutId4=&setInstruction4=&repInstruction4=&weightInstruction4=&restInstruction4="
  }
}
```

So, client_update_form is a string and looks like url parameters.

Use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse the string into an array:

```
parse_str( $input->client_update_form, $client_update_form );
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  ["client_id"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["squat_max"]=>
  string(3) "300"
  ["deadlift_max"]=>
  string(3) "100"
  ["bench_max"]=>
  string(3) "275"
}
```

So, your value is now in `$client_update_form['client_id']`.

Complete code:

```
$input = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
parse_str( $input->client_update_form, $client_update_form );
echo $client_update_form['client_id'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gerald! This is exactly what I needed and I will mark you answer as the correct solution.